# "Failed to load module script" error after running production build from Docker on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, docker, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm trying to run my Nuxt 3.6.5 app on Mixrosoft Azure cluster, but I see just a blank page with an error:

**Failed to load module script**: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

Running the app with dev server or nuxt preview runs without issues.

Does somebody know what am I possibly doing wrong?

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18
COPY --from=build /app/.output /app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "--trace-warnings", "/app/server/index.mjs"]
```